# what are escape characters and format characters used for

Tags: python

so i'm not exactly sure what they are used for like what does /n mean and whats %s for? im just not sure what I can use them for and what they are for

i'm just starting python so any help would be nice.

Comment: \n is a newline character, %s is used for formatting strings

Comment: Read [this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language)

Comment: i know it's a dumb question so thanks for answering me

Answer (score 1):

"Escape characters" are characters that are hard to type normally but that nonetheless we need to be able to represent in strings. For example:

```
"\n"  # newline
"\r"  # carriage return
"\t"  # tab
"\xAC"  # whatever character the hex code AC corresponds to
```

[Wikipedia elaborates on these, and provides a list of them in C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_sequences_in_C). And a list of escape characters that exist in python specifically [can be found here](https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/strings.html). You'll notice that it's more or less the same list - over time, languages have mostly standardized.

---

In general, the backslash `\` is used to escape other characters - such as in all case of the above. Note that `\\` is itself an escape character, which produces a backslash that *doesn't* escape other characters. In other contexts, like in [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html), backslashes can escape characters like `*`, `$`, `[`, etc. and make it so that they don't do anything when normally they would serve as a signal to do something. Rather than "Escape characters", it would be better to call these "escape**d** characters".

---

Some languages, like C, provide *format strings* - another special case. The purpose of format strings is to make it easier to print things: instead of doing

```
printf("My mother's name is " + name + " and she is " + age + " years old");
```

you can do

```
printf("My mother's name is %s and she is %d years old", name, age);
```

Python supports a similar syntax:

```
print("My name is %s and I am %d years old" % (name, age))
```

Here, instead of backslash (because backslash is *already* being used to escape characters), the `%` character is used to escape other strings. A token like `%s` or `%d` tells the function to substitute something in for it, and the letter determines what variable type:

```
"%s" % string
"%d" % int
"%f" % float
```

And, since it's necessary sometimes to type `%` literally, `%%` makes that happen, the same way as `\\` does for backslash.

Modern python also provides a newer type of format strings, which are detailed [in this documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/string.html#format-string-syntax)

---

A lot of different systems use the idea of escape characters differently - one I haven't mentioned is python's `datetime` module. A safe bet is to assume the basic escape characters (the ones in the first section of my answer) apply, and check the documentation carefully to see if there are others that you need to be aware of in the context.